# Python, Tkinter. Изменить расширение и взять цифру из имени файла

Tags: python, tkinter, text

Суть задачи такова: пользователь выбирает текстовый документ через `askopenfilename`, который имеет вид `textX.txt`, где `X` -- цифра (например, `text0.txt`).

Вопрос в том, как убрать убрать расширение `.txt`, заменив его на `.gif`, и получить число `Х`.

В конечном счёте должно получится `imgX.gif`.

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog  import askopenfilename   

class App:
   def __init__(self, master):

    frame = Frame(master)
    frame.pack()

    self.button = Button(frame, text="QUIT", command=frame.quit)
    self.button.pack(side=BOTTOM)

    self.text = Text(frame)
    self.text.pack(side=BOTTOM)

    self.choosen = askopenfilename(initialdir='files/')
    self.text.insert(END,open(self.choosen).read())


    ###RIGHT HERE###
    self.link  = PhotoImage(file=##########)
    self.image = Label(frame,image=self.link) 
    self.image.pack(side=TOP)

root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В вашем случае будет удобно написать вспомогательную функцию, которая:

1. выделяет в пути имя файла;
2. выполняет замену;
3. формирует новый путь.

Для разделения пути и финального объединения лучше воспользоваться функциями из `os.path` — `split` (разбиение) и `join` (слияние). Саму замену же удобно сделать при помощи регулярных выражений.

Функция может иметь следующий вид.

```
import os.path
import re

def get_img_name(txt_path):
    # Разделяем путь и имя файла
    (path, txt_name) = os.path.split(txt_path)
    # Выполняем замену
    gif_name = re.sub(r"^text(\d+)\.txt$", r"img\1.gif", txt_name)
    # Возвращаем новый путь
    return os.path.join(path, gif_name)
```

Здесь `path_txt` — путь к файлу textX.txt.

Регулярное выражение (шаблон поиска и замены) включает следующие элементы:

- `^` — признак начала текста,
- `\d` — одиночная цифра,
- `\d+` — последовательность цифр (одна и более),
- `( )` — позволяют выделить группу символов и сослаться на неё в строке замены через `\1`,
- `$` — признак конца текста.

`re.sub` принимает три аргумента: регулярное выражение; текст, на который выполняется замена; исходная строка.

Пример выполнения:

```
print get_img_name('/tmp/test/text12.txt')
```

> /tmp/test/img12.gif

Стоит также дополнить функцию проверками на возможные исключительные ситуации и ошибочные входные данные. Здесь для краткости проверки были опущены. Поэтому если имя не будет соответствовать шаблону `textX.txt`, то замена не будет выполнена.

[Документация на библиотеку `os.path`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html)

[Документация на библиотеку `re`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Comment: Совершенно не понятно, зачем для такой простейшей операции использовать регулярные выражения!?

Comment: Регулярные выражения не так уж и сложны (тут всего одна команда используется), поэтому встречный вопрос: а почему нет? С другой стороны функция получается универсальной и автор вопроса в подобной ситуации, когда шаблон имени будет сложнее, сможет использовать её же. К тому же, на мой взгляд, читаемость регулярного выражения (если, конечно, программист знаком с ними) всё же выше, чем у срезов строк с константами, зависящими от строки.

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас все файлы начинаются с одного и того же слова "text", то обработать имя файла можно гораздо проще:

```
old_filename = filename.split('.')
new_filename = 'img' + old_filename[0][4:] + '.gif'
```

Comment: В принципе, можно уложиться и в одну строку `'img' + filename.split('.')[0][4:] + 'gif'`

Comment: Не хочет менять само имя на **"img"** -- меняет лишь разрешение.

Comment: Если имя файла у вас точно такое же, как указано в вопросе: `textXXX.txt`, то должно работать! Или вы что-то делаете неправильно. Да, и часть после точки называется расширение.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно что-то наподобие [`os.path.splitext`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext):

```
namewithoutext = os.path.splitext(self.choosen)[0]
```

Прибавить `.gif`, надеюсь, не проблема.

---

Чтобы извлечь финальные цифры, проще всего наверное использовать регулярку:

```
import re
re.findall(r"\d+$", namewithoutext)
```

---

Чтобы откусить найденное число, можно сделать просто

```
nakedname = namewithoutext[:-len(trailingnumber)]
```

Comment: Если брать **splitext**, то получается _textЧИСЛО_, а не _text_.
Со отбором числа спасибо!

Comment: @CockLobster: ну да, а это и имел в виду? А вам нужно ещё и число откусить?

Comment: Да, нужно "откусить". :0

Comment: @CockLobster: окей, добавил. но тогда, возможно, лучше сделать регулярку посложнее, как в другом ответе.